# What am I missing from my initial attempt at getting default routes to work in ember?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-rails

Currently, the console says none of the templates can be found, and yet, when I console.log Ember.Templates, they are all there.

What is going on? I've been googling for hours.
(I'm new to ember, so, I'm probably searching incorrectly due to not knowing all the nomenclature yet... but seriously... this should work out of the box, yeah?)

here is a picture of what I'm experiencing:

[image]
(sorry for large size)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your template names are nested, but shouldn't be.  The `application` template shouldn't have `app/application` in front of it etc.

`foo/bar` would represent a `resource.route`

```
App.Router.map(function(){
  this.resource('foo', function(){
    this.route('bar');
  });
});
```

Comment: is there a configuration option to tell ember that the root path is `app`?

Comment: well, anyway, you were right. I moved all my ember files in to `Rails.root/app/assets/javascripts` instead of `Rails.root/app/assets/javascripts/app` and it started working. 

thank you!

Comment: There isn't one that I'm aware of for the templates. But you can create a view for each route and tell it to use that templateName... That sounds like a lot of work though, and wouldn't be super easy to debug when you're confused why it isn't working